# Netbeans 6.8 - Alternative compile and runtime jdks/jre versions

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.8

Have a scenario where i need to compile my project with jdk 1.5 but run it with jre 1.6. I can't find a way to switch the jre that is used when running my program. I read something about execution profiles in an earlier version of netbeans, but 6.8 doesn't seem to support this. Any ideas?

[Seems easy to do in eclipse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327656/specifying-an-alternative-jre-in-eclipse-for-an-application-launched-from-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  go to project-> properties - > sources ->binary source format and you pick your jdk 1.5 in your case. In libraries you can pick Java Platform