# running 32&64-bit java code

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, cplex

I am developing a Java program that calls a 32-bit CPLEX Optimizer,
But I will run this code on a 64-bit machine.
 
Can I run part of program in 64-bit and other parts in 32-bit?

Answer (score 3):

If it's a separate program that runs in its own process, there's no problem.  32-bit and 64-bit processes can coexist on the same system.

If it's a Java library that loads a 32-bit native library into the JVM (e.g. with JNI), it'll only work in a 32-bit JVM process.

Comment: Command for what?  There's no magic pill that makes 32-bit libraries work in 64-bit processes, if that's what you're asking.  You could try running the optimizer in a separate 32-bit JVM process, alongside the 64-bit one, and have the two JVMs communicate using something like RMI.

Comment: Once you install a 32 bit JRE on your system you need to configure your IDE to use it.  For Eclipse instructions check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/327661/1118307 .

Comment: i actually want to run this program in 64bit. i install 64bit java.ans set net beans to use 64bit jdk, but when calling the cplex library  show error. may exit some command to temporary convert to 32bit?

Comment: @mehdifallahi You can "convert" a 32-bit shared library by re-compiling it from source as a 64-bit library. (Plus fix any bugs in the code as this is not always trivial) If this sounds like a headache, it is the sort of headache that Java is designed to solve.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, that only works if you have the source code.  In this case it seems to be a third-party commercial library.

Comment: @mehdifallahi, no, there's no command to "temporarily convert" a 64-bit process into a 32-bit process.  They're different instruction sets and different memory layouts.  If the vendor doesn't provide a 64-bit version of the library you're using, you'll need to use the workaround with a separate 32-bit JVM.  (Or just run your whole application in a 32-bit JVM.)

Comment: @Wyzard The vendor will have the source. I assume that OP knows that he can't compile the source if he doesn't have it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To use a 32-bit shared library from a 64-bit process you need to have two processes. One which has your 64-bit JVM which calls a 32-bit process which holds your shared library.

The other option is to recompile your shared library from source as a 64-bit library.